# Sharing Tor socksport via wired ethernet connection?

Tags: networking, vpn, sharing, tor, socks5

Using Ubuntu 16.04 on both machines.

I've been able to share my VPN IP between devices with an ethernet cable.

The host running VPN and Tor: 
IPv4 Settings: "Shared to other computers"
IP Address: 10.42.0.1
Subnet: 255.255.255.0

The client:
IP Address: 10.42.0.2
Broadcast Address: 10.42.0.255
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default Route: 10.42.0.1

This configuration works fine for sharing my VPN IP, I'm not clear on how to use the Hosts Tor socksport from the client device.